# How can I make this Angular navigation forcefully reload a certain component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am working on a navigation system for an Angular 14 app.

In `app-routing.module.ts` I have:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/pages/about/about.component';
import { TermsComponent } from './components/pages/terms/terms.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'terms', component: TermsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

In `navbar.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  public menuItems: any[] = [
    {
      route: '',
      text: 'Home',
    },
    {
      route: '/about',
      text: 'About',
    },
    {
      route: '/terms',
      text: 'Terms and Conditions',
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

In `navbar.component.html` I have:

```
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="brand">Logo</a>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
      <a [routerLink]="[item.route]" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">
        {{ item.text }}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

There is a Stackblitz **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-kkxvxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.html)** with all the code.

#### The goal

The goal is to be able to choose which of the pages (components) should *reload* upon clicking its corresponding router link, *even if the component is already loaded*.

For example, if I want (only) the "Terms and Conditions" to always reload, I would have:

```
public menuItems: any[] = [
    {
      route: '',
      text: 'Home',
      reload: false
    },
    {
      route: '/about',
      text: 'About',
      reload: false
    },
    {
      route: '/terms',
      text: 'Terms and Conditions',
      reload: true
    },
  ];
```

#### EDIT

Here is a solution that works but is **redundant and it lacks flexibility**:

In `navbar.component.html` I have added a `reloadComponent()`method:

```
public menuItems: any[] = [
    {
      route: '',
      text: 'Home',
      reload: false
    },
    {
      route: '/about',
      text: 'About',
      reload: false
    },
    {
      route: '/terms',
      text: 'Terms and Conditions',
      reload: true
    },
  ];
  
  public reloadComponent(item: any){
    if (item.reload && window.location.pathname == '/terms' ) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
```

In `navbar.component.html` I have added:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
  <a [routerLink]="[item.route]" [routerLinkActive]="'active'" (click)="reloadComponent(item)">
    {{ item.text }}
  </a>
</li>
```

I consider this solution, to be honest, dumb. It's only quality its that it works, for the particular case it is needed for.

I wish there was a way that I could reload the component that corresponds to the clicked menu item and *not the current page*.

#### Questions

1. How can I achieve this goal?
2. Is there a flexible and "elegant" solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement RouteReuseStrategy, which allows you to control the reusability of the components, and you can choose which components should be cached and reused when the user navigates to a route they have already visited.

```js
import { RouteReuseStrategy, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  private storedRouteHandles = new Map<string, DetachedRouteHandle>();

  shouldReuseRoute(current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    this.storedRouteHandles.set(route.routeConfig.path, handle);
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
    return this.storedRouteHandles.get(route.routeConfig.path);
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.storedRouteHandles.has(route.routeConfig.path);
  }

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  deleteRouteSnapshot(path: string): void {
    this.storedRouteHandles.delete(path);
  }
}
```

You need to register it into app module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomRouteReuseStrategy } from './custom-route-reuse-strategy';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      // ...
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomRouteReuseStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the ActivatedRouteSnapshot you should have access to that custom route information:"reload: true":

```js
 shouldReuseRoute(current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    // Check if the custom parameter "myParam" exists in the route's data.
    const myParam = current.data && current.data['myParam'];

    // If "myParam" is set to "reuse", reuse the current route.
    if (myParam === 'reuse') {
      return true;
    }

    // Otherwise, create a new component.
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that is a workaround. I would give a try to that RouteReuseStrategy. Otherwise you could extract "reloadComponent" into an abstract base component and, any component which should be reloadable should inherit from it.

Comment: The workaround males `reload: false` irrelevant :)
`

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your router config

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
  })],
```

Along with this you will have to disable click with condition reload true/false.

Docs link: https://angular.io/api/router/OnSameUrlNavigation

Comment: What I want is to be able to _choose_ which component to reload. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can create sort of fake dynamic route to re-render the components.

Comment: It does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution proposed by @Zsolt Balint almost works perfect, but throws this error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: route.routeConfig is null". I fixed changed *route.routeConfig.path* to *route._routerState.url*

```js
import { RouteReuseStrategy, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  private storedRouteHandles = new Map<string, DetachedRouteHandle>();

  shouldReuseRoute(current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    // Check if the custom parameter "myParam" exists in the route's data.
    const myParam = current.data && current.data['myParam'];

    // If "myParam" is set to "reuse", reuse the current route.
    if (myParam === 'reuse') {
      return true;
    }

    // Otherwise, create a new component.
    return false;
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    //@ts-ignore
    this.storedRouteHandles.set(route._routerState.url, handle);
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
        //@ts-ignore
    return this.storedRouteHandles.get(route._routerState.url);
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    //@ts-ignore
    return this.storedRouteHandles.has(route._routerState.url);
  }

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return true;
  }

  deleteRouteSnapshot(path: string): void {
    this.storedRouteHandles.delete(path);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set state data to your route, and in it's components you could validate if the route state snapshot has the flag you refresh the page.

Example: When you render your menu, you could do something like this:

**navbar.component.html**

```
    <nav>
   <a href="#" class="brand">Logo</a>
   <ul class="navigation">
      <li *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
         <a [routerLink]="[item.route]" [routerLinkActive]="'active'" [state]="{ reload:item.reload}">
         {{ item.text }}
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

And on each component belonging to your route, do something like this.

```
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
    boolean shouldPageReload = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state["reload"]

    if (shouldPageReload) {
        // reload your component
    }
}
```

For more information please check this article about passing data to your routes

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-data-to-route/

Comment: It throws this error: `Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with *`.

Comment: The line `this.shouldPageReload = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state['reload']` throws an `Object is possibly 'null'` error.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir you are right, I just missed deleting double ** in [state] property. I hope you find the right answer to your question. And in the .ts I just added secure navigation (?) to prevent an error when state is not found-